# How can I execute a Java command on nodeJS?

Tags: java, node.js, command, spawn

I'm trying to compile a .java file with the javac command then I want to to execute it with the java command. Here is what I'm trying :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var javac  = spawn('javac', [' C:/Users/Administator/Desktop/Hello.java']);
var javaa  = spawn('java', [' C:/Users/Administator/Desktop/Hello']);

javac.stdout.on('data', function out(data) {
    console.log(data);
    javaa.stdout.on('data', function out(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    javaa.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("error");
    });

    javaa.on('exit', function out(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

javac.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("error");
});

javac.on('exit', function out(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you spawn java until javac is done? You cannot run your java program until it is already compiled after all.

Comment: Have you read the node.js [documentation on child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) already? I think your answer is there. Bottom line is register for an event in javac that let you know when it's done; then run the other process.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var opts = {stdio: 'inherit'} ;
var javac = spawn('javac', [' C:/Users/Administator/Desktop/Hello.java'], opts);

javac.on('close', function (code) {
    if (code === 0) {
        var javaa  = spawn('java', [' C:/Users/Administator/Desktop/Hello'], opts);
    }
});
```